# Why my program crashes after second usage of a string in different functions?

Tags: c, json, string, cjson

When I run my program , it calls a function that have a "char *msgtype" and this function work probably but when another function use a different "char *msgtype" in it when program reach the line that contain it , program crashes(and even when the firs function is called for second time program crashes). What is the problem ?

and if I change the name in the second function it just work one time and after calling that function again program crashes !

```
void fun1(){
    ...

    cJSON *root = cJSON_Parse(buffer);
    char *msgtype = cJSON_GetObjectItem(root,"type")->valuestring;

    ...

    free(msgtype);
    cJSON_Delete(root);

    ...
}

void fun2(){
    ...

    cJSON *root = cJSON_Parse(buffer);
    char *msgtype = cJSON_GetObjectItem(root,"type")->valuestring;//it crashes here

    ...

    free(msgtype);
    cJSON_Delete(root);

    ...
}

int main(){
    fun1();
    fun2();//it crashes inside this function !
}
```

Comment: Where does `buffer` come from? is it identical in both calls?

Comment: And also, what is `...` before the parse function?

Comment: Take a look at [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ctx buffer comes from a server

Comment: @ctx in the middle " ..." there is an if with strcmp()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what `cJSON_GetObjectItem()` returns? Is it a pointer into a data structure, or a copy of the data? If it returns a pointer to part of the bigger structure, that should not be freed with `free()` — it would be freed when you destroy the `cjSON` object.

If you take a look at the code for `get_object_item()` — which is called directly from  `cJSON_GetObjectItem()` in [`cJSON.c`](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON/blob/master/cJSON.c), you will see it returns a pointer into the middle of a `cJSON` object.  You cannot afford to call `free()` on that return value.  You should only call `cJSON_Delete()` on the complete object.  By calling `free(msgtype)`, you are wrecking the integrity of the `root` data structure — and you probably end up with a double-free problem too.

If it is available for your platform, use [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) to analyze what's going wrong — it will probably tell you.  If your system's `malloc()` implementation has debugging hooks (the version on macOS, for example, does), consider using them.